# What exactly is it Xamarin.android.support.v7.appcompat

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm working with Xamarin.Android.
`Appcompat` is actually necessary for use material design because the nougat package (Android.support.design) requires it.
But why, for example, if I work only with API 27, I must add the `AppCompat` package? In my `toolBox` i've not the `floatingActionButton`, `NavigationDrawer` etc.. so I must add this packet to `unlock` them. 
What is exactly this package? I've read on the web that this package works with backward compatibility but I only work with new APIs, so why I must install it?
Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html has quite a bit of information as to the WHY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppCompat should add the functionality of the latest API to older APIs when needed. For instance, lollipop added the CardView class, which can be used in older Android APIs when AppCompat is used, with some minor differences (some of the Android L animations may not apply on older versions of Android for example). It is recommended to use AppCompat in most cases since more users will be able to run your app when you do (depending on your MinSdkVersion). If you want to know what classes you can access in AppCompat, you can take a look at the features here:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin.Android.AppCompat is just what it says.  Its a library for App Compatibility for backward compatibility for previous versions of Android and more specifically this version (v7) brings support for Action Bar support.  Read more here :
[AppCompat](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv7appcompat)

Comment: ok but why I must add it to my project for use material design? It's ridicolous, i want only work with new APIs

Comment: In order to submit your app and use Material Design that's a required side dependency.  It will not hurt your app to have that there.

Answer (score 0):

They are libraries used for accessing the latest features of an Android OS version. It is backward compatible by the way.